# Health Dashboard for a set of webservices

Tags: web-services, health-monitoring

I am planning to build a health dashboard with a good feel UI. The basic intent of the health dashboard is to test the health of around 150 web services hosted on various servers. I understand that "HEALTH" is very abstract. I am planning to start off with measuring the latency. I am just not able to get a break through about how should I start about this. Kindly please help, searched around the net for months now and STACKOVERFLOW is my last hope !!

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Should ‘Hi’, ‘thanks’ and taglines and salutations be removed from posts? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts. There's no need to add "Hi" and "Thanks" to posts. Getting an up-vote or acceptance is thanks enough :) You can edit question and delete it: Any help would be very appreciated.Thanks and may be "and STACKOVERFLOW is my last hope !!" And Read FAQ please

Answer (score 1):

Check out [op5](http://www.op5.com/op5-features/monitoring-web-services/) which will monitor web services and other things.